# Ambiguious anaphora in a speech

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

On October 31, 2014, President Obama spoke on the topic of women and the economy. Here's a section of the speech.

> Moms and dads deserve a great place to drop their kids off every day
>   that doesn’t cost them an arm and a leg.  We need better childcare,
>   daycare, early childhood education policies.  (Applause.)  In many
>   states, sending your child to daycare costs more than sending them to
>   a public university.
>
> AUDIENCE MEMBER:  True!
>
> THE PRESIDENT:  True.  (Laughter.)  And too often, parents have no
>   choice but to put their kids in cheaper daycare that maybe doesn’t
>   have the kinds of programming that makes a big difference in a child’s
>   development.  And sometimes there may just not be any slots, or the
>   best programs may be too far away.  And sometimes, someone, usually
>   mom, leaves the workplace to stay home with the kids, which then
>   leaves her earning a lower wage for the rest of her life as a result. 
>   And that’s not a choice we want Americans to make.
>   [Remarks by the President on Women and the Economy -- Providence, RI](http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2014/10/31/remarks-president-women-and-economy-providence-ri)

In the last sentence, there are several anaphora that are ambiguous. I am concerned with the first anaphora: *that.* (I'm also concerned with the *we*, but let us leave that for another topic.)

Does *that* refer to

1. The parents' choice of cheaper daycare with poorer programming, or
2. The mom's choice of leaving the workplace to stay at home with the kids, or
3. The mom's forced choice of receiving a lower wage for life?

As I recall, most often, the anaphora binds more tightly with the closest referent. This would seem to strengthen 2 and 3. But since the president went on to propose enrolling 6 million children in high-quality preschool, perhaps he had 1 in mind.

But a quick search on "that's not a choice we want Americans to make" will show many pundits up in arms:

- Ouch: Obama Claims America Doesn't Want Stay-At-Home Moms [(Townhall)](http://townhall.com/tipsheet/sarahjeanseman/2014/10/31/ouch-obama-claims-america-doesnt-want-stayathome-moms-n1912706)
- 3 Reasons President Obama Is Wrong About Stay-At-Home Mothers [(Federalist)](http://thefederalist.com/2014/10/31/3-reasons-president-obama-is-wrong-about-stay-at-home-mothers/)
- Staying at Home is Not a Choice We Want Americans to Make [(Living Whole)](http://www.livingwhole.org/staying-at-home-is-not-a-choice-we-want-americans-to-make/)

So here's my question: To what does the *that* refer to in the last sentence of the quote? Please, no political debating here. I'm looking for the plain sense of the English being used.

Answer (score 0):

A *choice* is usually between two option. It may be that Presidant Obama does not want Americans to choose between sub-standard daycare and staying home to care for the children (it may also be that he doesn't want them to have to choose between staying indoors and going out in the rain).

Grammatically, it could also be that he doesn't want them to make the choice of staying with the children (indoors) and logically does want them to go out to work; but if that were the intention, he would not have said there is no choice but cheaper, substandard daycare. He would instead have called it healthy, ordinary weather - I mean the normal type of childcare.